# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority?

Tags: docker

Из-за чего возникает ошибка?

```
Step 1/7 : FROM  test.tes.gd:5000/tre-packages:latest
ERROR: Service 'tes-app' failed to build: Get https://test.tes.gd:5000/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Comment: какая ОС у вас?

Comment: ubuntu и centos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

1) скачайте файл cacert.pem с сайта http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

2) скопируйте cacert.pem в /etc/pki/trust/anchors/

3) sudo update-ca-certificates

4) sudo systemctl docker stop

5) sudo systemctl docker start